# How do I enter my container if dokku enter <app> does nothing?

Tags: dokku

I have a simple dokku app using [herokuish buildpack-php](https://github.com/gliderlabs/herokuish/tree/master/buildpacks/buildpack-php) with a procfile: `web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/`

If I try to enter the app with `dokku enter <appname>` nothing happens, and I am simply returned to my host shell.

I can run `dokku run <appname> bash` and get a shell, but is, as far as I understand from [the documentation](https://github.com/dokku/dokku/blob/master/docs/deployment/one-off-processes.md) placing me in a new container and not in the existing/running one I need access to:

> The run command can be used to run a one-off process for a specific command. This will start a new container and run the desired command within that container.

How can I fix this so I can enter my running container?

Comment: Same here. I have 2 dokku servers. dokku enter works on only 1 of them...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are in the local directory for your app, doing the following will take you into the running container for it:

`dokku enter web.1`

I've done this a few times today!

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can enter your container using docker. For doing so, run `docker ps` and note the container ID. Afterwards, run `docker exec -it container_id /bin/bash`.